# Error while loading shared libraries - Using CUnit on Netbeans

Tags: c, unit-testing, netbeans, cygwin, cunit

I am a newbie working with Cygwin and CUnit. I have to develop some Unit Tests using CUnit and Netbeans and I have followed the next tutorial:

https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/cnd/c-unit-test.html?print=yes#project

At the end, when I was trying to run the first example test I got stocked by an error:

```
  0 [main] make 4380 C:\cygwin\bin\make.exe: *** fatal error - error while loading shared libraries: /cygdrive/C/Program Files/NetBeans 8.0.2/ide/bin/nativeexecution/Windows-x86_64/unbuffer.dll: cannot open shared object file: Exec format error

448 [main] make 4380 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to make.exe.stackdump
```

I don't know if this has relation to the Cygwin version I have, I have a computer running Windows 7 Enterprise 64bits edition. I have configured my C project to use Cygwin 64bits edition...

Could you please share any idea about how I can solve this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but in my case I was trying to run CppUnit tests in Netbeans. I was using make provided by MSYS2 and it was failing to load unbuffer.dll, but error was "No such file or directory". I switched the make from MSYS2 for the one found in MSYS and the error went away. You could try this as a workaround.

Comment: Provide more info on how to switch to the MSYS make by adding URL's to explanations and/or telling him what the steps are.

Answer (score -1):

I found sole here:
https://bz.apache.org/netbeans/attachment.cgi?id=164026&action=edit

Need download new version of **unbuffer.dll**.

Yar

Comment: I suggest you elaborate on your answer and explain your proposed solution in relation to the errors received.